# Core Data import large amount of data

Tags: performance, core-data, import

I am inserting a large amount of entities when my iOS app first runs. I am wondering how many items I can insert in my context before saving? I am getting a large JSON object from a web call. From the JSON I extract tons of entities and insert them.

How should I handle a large amount of insertions?

Thank you

Comment: How much does the loaded JSON weighs? Kbs? Mbs? Gbs?

Comment: it can vary quite a bit, but for now the most it has been was 740K

Answer (score 0, accepted):

zumzum,

There are many issues to worry about when importing a large number of items into Core Data.

The first and most important issue is managing memory. Large JSON documents parse into a huge number of small items. These force the irreversible growth of your resident VM footprint. This resident footprint is the number one reason apps are killed by the OS. You can have small size of allocated memory and still be killed due to the size of your resident footprint.

Hence, large documents should be processed in stages with aggressive intermediate memory cleanup operations. Using a concurrent MOC with resets between operations is the way to go. I then implement a trailing trimming pattern to clean up any superfluous memory retained in my main thread MOCs.

Andrew

Comment: Comments below were great and they make sense. It is true since I am in the Kb order at the moment this is probably premature optimization. However, I am interested in the best approach to go about this just as general knowledge. I've profiled the app during the import and performing progressive cleanup by saving and resetting the context helped performance in my scenario. So, I'm marking this as the answer that worked best for me for now.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have no problems regarding the size of the context before saving, but you should definitely execute this on a background thread since it will most likely freeze the app for a while. If this happens only the first time you launch the app you can put an progress indicator or something on the main thread while saving the context on a background thread.

Refer to the first answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10438218/best-practice-for-a-long-running-foreground-operation-that-uses-core-data) for details on core data's concurrent context save.

Comment: I think my main concern is not main thread or not, I am wondering about the memory. True maybe my scenario will be just fine, but, what is the rule? Meaning, is core data going to manage memory on the phone while inserting tons of entities in the one context?

Comment: There is no particular element describing the unsaved context in Apple's docs, however, considering BLOBs (Binary Large OBjects) that obviously need to be loaded/saved in a single context object, this is what the docs state: "A loose rule of thumb is that objects in the order of kilobytes in size are of a “modest” sized and those in the order of megabytes in size are “large” sized. Some developers have achieved good performance with 10MB BLOBs in a database." In other words, having an unsaved context in the order of kilobytes is safe.

Comment: It might be a premature optimization to worry about it at this point. The rule of thumb is don't worry about it if and until you need to. The Instruments profiling tools will tell you everything you need, but with only 740K, I wouldn't be too worried about it. I've processed in somewhere around 8-10MB worth of JSON before and it went just fine. Ultimately I did have to optimize some things, but I didn't know what those things were until I started seeing issues.